# How to add digital signature to pdf in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, digital-signature, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am generating pdf using [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) and I am also using `prawntable` for pdfs which needs to be password protected. Since wicked pdf doesnt supports password protected pdf generation.

Is there any way to add a digital signature which is in `.pfx` format to pdf.?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: It looks to me like this q is 100% programming related! I agree the question could be clearer...

Comment: If I am creating a pdf using a program and I can secure it through a password using a program, why cant I add a signature to that using a program??

Comment: It is possible to do both in principle (i don't know whether it is possible with your libraries). But your question sounded as if you mixed those two things up.

Answer (score 2):

**Passwording pdf files vs digitally signing them**

Passwording a pdf file encrypts the file. You will need to find a pdf library/toolkit to do that for you. If you can't find one with a ruby API, then you can call it as a command from ruby. The latter is not as elegant but works fine. (Be sure to catch and handle errors.)

Digitally signing a pdf is completely different than encryption. The result of signing is a pdf with one or more digital signatures. You use either a library to sign a file locally or, for a more dependable system, sign the file via a dedicated appliance that also holds the signer's private key and certificate.

Unlike password protection/encryption, anyone who receives a digitally signed pdf file can read the file's content. The digital signatures provide the relying party (the recipient) with assurances about:

- the identity of the person who signed the file
- the integrity of the file (confirming that it wasn't changed since signing)
- the non-reputability of the file (confirming that the signer can't claim that they hadn't signed the file)

An important issue is that having a signer's private key on the file system of a regular computer/server is not secure enough to provide any guarantee against repudiation by the signer--she could truthfully say that there is no way to assure that her "signature" was not forged by un-authorized use of the pfx file.

Answer (score 1):

The Origami library has a very basic support for PDF digital signatures and there is sample code for this at https://github.com/gdelugre/origami/blob/master/examples/signature/signature.rb.